# Can you run Mac OSX in Virtual box on an AMD pc?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, cpu

I thought about coding a few iOS apps. To do that you need a mac.
I have an AMD based pc and I don't want to buy a mac. So I wonder if its possible to run mac OSX in virtual box on an AMD pc.

Thanks

Comment: While this may or may not be **technically** possible, it is **not** legally possible without violating the copyright license of Apple Mac OS X. If you violate the copyright license of a piece of software, you no longer have any right to possess or use that software, or you are breaking international law. This is a serious crime in many countries and is definitely, unambiguously, illegal in the country in which StackExchange operates, the USA. There is no way to do this that is legal without purchasing an actual Mac -- the hardware -- from Apple.

Comment: StackExchange allows discussion of things that are "grey areas", but this isn't even close to being a grey area. This is unquestionably, unambiguously, illegal and it should not be discussed on the StackExchange network.

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal): "Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited." Talking about how to do something that **cannot possibly be done legally** is tantamount to "engaging in illegal activity".

Comment: It probably isn't technically possible either (IIRC most hackintoshes that run AMD need a custom kernel. Ditto with atoms). You'd also need to pirate a copy to run it on a VM if you've never owned a mac. I've chosen to close as unclear since as is, the question is hypothetical, shows no research effort and lacks details to actual issues faced *secondary* to acceptability of hackintosh questions on the site.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS is not licensed for anything other than Apple hardware.

Comment: This is true, so don't sign the licence.

Comment: Pirating software & OS is not a supported subject in these forums.

Comment: You can buy Mac OSX and then make a HackingTosh, which is legal.

Comment: No, it isn't, really.

Comment: Whether this is legal will depend on where you live, please check local laws.

Comment: The copyright license of Mac OS X is not subject to regional variations, unless some part of it is deemed unconscionable (I have never heard of such a ruling thus far). This answer is correct, and this post should be closed for talking about activity that clearly and unambiguously would **necessarily** break the law (at least in the US, and since SE is based in New York, that's what counts). This is even less gray area than the breaking DRM issue because the copyright license is pretty obvious: you can only run Mac OS X on Apple hardware.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Well depends on the spec of the cpu and amount of RAM. There is an option in virtual box you have to click to change the boot loader, it is clearly labelled for use with mac-os.

Comment: I know. But I have an AMD based pc. I know Mac OSX only can run on Intel based systems. But does this also count when you are running a virtual system?

Comment: It looks like oricle are under a lot of legal pressure from apple so they are not making it easy, however I suspect it is still possible you just need to find a site that apple's lawyers have not sat on https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=31104

Comment: There isn't much "legal pressure". In order to run MacOS X, a VM must emulate one quite trivial chip existing in every Macintosh which contains DRM information needed to boot MacOS X. Doing that would be a clear DMCA violation.

Comment: @gnasher729 that depends where you live, and the liberality of the laws there.